# Is the constructor not called for function parameters?

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor, pass-by-value

So, this might be kinda of an embarrassing question. I was re-enforcing my C++ basics and I ran into this curious case.

The interesting part is that upon entering the function, the constructor is not called for the object lb but upon leaving the function the destructor is called for lb, I presume.

How could this be possible? Either both the constructor & destructor should be called when they enter the function. OR if only the destructor is being called then should lead to segmentation errors, I expect?

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;

class B {
public:
  B() {
    cout<<"Construct B"<<endl;
  }
  virtual ~B() {
     cout<<"Destruct B"<<endl;
  }
};

bool FuncByVal(B lb)
{
   return true;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   B b;
   FuncByVal(b);
   return 0;
}
```

And the output is:
Construct B
Destruct B
Destruct B

I tested on Visual Studio 2012 under Windows 8.1 and Eclipse with MinGW under Windows 8.1.

Plus I tested under Linux (eclipse+gcc), as well, just to be sure.

p.s. for copy-by-reference the outputs were as I expected, i.e., only one constructor call and one destructor was called for the same code.

Comment: You didn't instrument the copy constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's being called is the object's copy constructor, not its default constructor. Since you didn't define the copy constructor explicitly the [compiler defined it implicitly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_member_functions) (with no output of course).

```
class B {
public:
  B() {
    cout<<"Construct B"<<endl;
  }

  /// Add this
  B(const B&) {
    cout<<"Copy B"<<endl;
  }

  virtual ~B() {
     cout<<"Destruct B"<<endl;
  }
};
```

Comment: wow ! thanks. I was blind. :D. I'll accept the answer in 8 minutes (says stackoverflow).

Comment: @JunaidNaseer no worries, recently a coworker who saw that the constructor/destructor calls weren't balanced. He too forgot to write a copy constructor and he deals with C++ daily.

Comment: @Motti: Fire him! (jokes)

Answer (score 4):

You are correct that a constructor for `lb` will be called upon entering `FuncByVal`. It's just the **copy** constructor, not the **default** constructor. Add this to your `B`:

```
B(const B& ) {
    cout << "Copy B\n";   
}
```

And your code prints:

> Construct B
>   Copy B
>   Destruct B
>   Destruct B

Comment: thanks for the quick reply as well, @Barry. I see, I was blind.